# What word do I use when in the situation that a student no longer needs to submit a homework?

Tags: word-request

For example, a student got really sick and the teacher assigned a homework, but because of this disease he no longer needs to do it. I thought about **"exempted"**.

Comment: Surely, you do not mean disease. You mean: due to illness the student has been excused from handing in his or her assignment. Please note: education is a very difficult field to do translation in. I speak fluent Spanish (quasi-native) and Portuguese (native) and I would never translate into either. I only translate into English and find that most of my colleagues can't do educational texts even if they are professional translators.

Comment: Also, it's homework or homework assignment, not "a homework".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Exempted" or "Exempt" is a good word for this. Google "exempt from homework" to see a number of natural-sounding usages. "Excused" could be used as well, but the other is probably better.

Comment: I disagree that exempted would be used here by a classroom teacher. Perhaps a student might be exempted from year-end exams or even from taking a test, but it is a heavy word for homework.

Comment: Student have excused absences and therefore do not need to hand in their homework.

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense for a different environment...like an employee  has e-learning tasks in the training program of the company and is exempt from some tasks during his vacation. I think exempt fits well, like in this example: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/nov/18/canada-homework-milley

Comment: @Lambie I don't agree. I work for a company that makes classroom software, and "exempt" is the term that teachers use for any kind of assignment, including homework. My understanding is that's fairly typical in standard-based grading.